# Text inside minipage is vertically centered instead of being aligned to top

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to put an image to the left of the page with some text to the right by using 2 minipages, but I can't figure out how to make the text in the minipage to the right start from the top as opposed to being vertically centered to the entire minipage. Here's the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \captionsetup{width=1\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{images/cc11a4a992acd97f9ad1d9c1301e0004.png}
        \caption{Ett typiskt treatment head i en medicinsk LINAC  \cite{borges_2011_monte}.} 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        Example
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

And here's the result:
[image]

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[t]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that makes the text go to the bottom of the minipage

Comment: no it aligns at the first (top) baseline but here that is the bottom edge of the picture, add `\vspace{0pt}` as first item in each minipage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great thanks

Answer (score 1):

by default `minipage` have reference point in the vertical centre, use

```
\begin{minipage}[t]
```

in each case, and start each page with

```
\vspace{0pt}
```

or vary the length as you see fit, so that the first reference point in the box is not the reference point of the image, which is its bottom edge.